# mysql dynamic column based on weekday

Tags: mysql, select, weekday

I have a table:

```
id 0_open 0_close 1_open 1_close 2_open 2_close 3_open 3_close 4_open 4_close 5_open 5_close 6_open 6_close

1 07:00 18:00 07:00 18:00 07:00 18:00 07:00 18:00 07:00 18:00 07:00 18:00 07:00 18:00
```

- Where **0-6** - weekday (From Mon to Sun);

How can I select rows:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE TIME(NOW()) BETWEEN 2_open AND 2_close
```

If today is Wednesday (Index: 2)?

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL structure is extremly off.

Usually one would create a table like this:

```
id, open, close, weekday
```

and you would be able to query it like this

```
SELECT open, close WHERE weekday = DAYOFWEEK()
```

I guess you cannot change it, so you are stuck with your current table. You can query your information like this:

```
SELECT 0_open, 0_close FROM table WHEN DAYOFWEEK() = 0
UNION
SELECT 1_open, 1_close FROM table WHEN DAYOFWEEK() = 1
UNION
SELECT 2_open, 2_close FROM table WHEN DAYOFWEEK() = 2
UNION
SELECT 3_open, 3_close FROM table WHEN DAYOFWEEK() = 3
UNION
SELECT 4_open, 4_close FROM table WHEN DAYOFWEEK() = 4
UNION
SELECT 5_open, 5_close FROM table WHEN DAYOFWEEK() = 5
UNION
SELECT 6_open, 6_close FROM table WHEN DAYOFWEEK() = 6
```

Answer (score 1):

It's something you have to handle in the business layer of the application (i.e. maybe a function in the middleware/backend layer that takes a date as an argument and returns column names).

Talking about the functions, you can also write a `function` in `MySQL` that takes a date and returns two values which can be used in the above query. You can make use of [DAYOFWEEK()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek) library function of `MySQL` to determine the column names.